# Glue Data write to Redshift too slow

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I am running a pyspark glue job with 10 DPU, the data in s3 is around 45 GB files split into 6 .csv files.

first question:
Its taking a lot of time to write data to Redshift from glue even tho I am running 10 DPUs

second:
How can I make it more faster and efficient , should I write the data back after transformation to s3 in parquet format and then may be use a COPY command to directly write data to Redshift?

Please suggest the best Ideas and approaches.

Comment: If you're not using `COPY` now, what are you using?  are you issuing `INSERT`?

Comment: I am writing data to redshift using aws glue dynamic frame

Comment: Can you update your question with the script and also are you using postgresql or redshift driver in your JDBC connection?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Sure will do the same today with few edits in my code. Thanks